# Joomla's jdoc:include has no output

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

Preface: This question relates specifically to "modules" type jdoc:include tags. I'm running J!1.5

So we've set up a series of template locations and mod_custom content blocks. Every other one of the content blocks are loading fine (e.g. the 'social' block, the 'recommendations' block'.)

However, we are running into a problem with a content block we are loading in the head tag. The content it is supposed to be loading is a series of FB-specific opengraph meta tags. It simply doesn't show up. If I move the content to another position in the template, it is still ignored, though I can move OTHER content to the current position and it is fine. It seems to be just this content block.

I've sanity-checked all the content & template XML, cleared the caches, everything. Here's the command I'm using to render the content:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="head" />
```

I suspect there may be a keyword clash, but I can't find anything of the sort on the J! documentation.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something related to the jdoc call of `<jdoc:include type="head" />` in your `<head></head>` tags

Try calling your module something else, like `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="headforFB" />`

Comment: I tried all that. I ended up moving the jdoc tag to the top of the head tag and it seemed to work. Although I found the solution, I'm not happy that it actually solved anything, so I'm writing it off as a PEBKAC error unless someone else has a good explanation.

Comment: Oh right, I would of thought this would of been the case anyway. Try posting your structure of index.php next time? :D